# How do I automatically set model properties when retrieved from the db?

Tags: laravel

In my route I have:

```
$products = Product::where('category',$category)->get();
return $products[0]->x;
```

How can I set up my Product model so that the route returns `abcd1234`?

This is what I currently have in my model:

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->x = 'abcd1234';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need an accessor.

**Add this to your `Product` model:**

```
public function getXAttribute()
{
    return 'abcd1234';
}
```

**Access it with:**

```
$product = Product::where('category', $category)->first();

return $product->x;
```

Having a 1 character attribute name may cause a problem though, id recommend changing the X to something with more than one character in camel case for the accessor.

Comment: Im not positive it would, but if it did, it would be due to the away accessors are named in camel case.  Just thought id throw that out there in case it didn't yield the desired result.  I doubt expect that in practice anyone would really name it `X`

Comment: The way accessors convert the name definitely does work with single character attributes: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L289-L294